# Dealing with ValueError: Grouper

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to take an average of columns with similar names using `.groupby()` and `.mean()`. Currently it is telling me that the values are not 1-Dimensional.

### The Error

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'Wavelength' not 1-dimensional
```

I have checked to make sure that the data frame is not MultiIndex as some of the limited stackoverflow questions regarding this issue have mentioned. The check I have done is to use `.columns.get_level_values(1)`. Argument of 0 gives me the columns names but argument of 1 gives an error saying that there is only 1 layer, not 2. `type(df)` does not print out MultiIndex so I am pretty positive that is not the case. Another stackoverflow comment was to change the names of the columns, but that would defeat the purpose since I will be using this script to process a large amount of files of similar structure.

### My Question

Where is this data not 1-dimensional if it is not due to MultiIndexing? How do I fix it such that I can use `groupby()` and `mean()` to take an average?

### The Code

```
final_list = [] 
for i in np.arange(0, len(tb_avg)): # tb_avg is a list of .csv file names that have a duplicate. file names are in the format "parameters_A" and it can go up to "_E"
    file_list = [] 
    for j in np.arange(0, int(tb_avg[i][1])): 
        file_list.append(tb_avg[i][0] + end[j]) # This is where _A.csv -> _E.csv is being added to complete the file name 
    working = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list], ignore_index=False, axis = 1)
    working = working.drop(['Wavelength.1'], axis=1)
    working = working.drop(index=0)
    working = working.groupby(by='Wavelength') # This is where the code fails
```

### The Data

```
  Wavelength                  S2c         S2 Wavelength                   S2c  \
1       1100  5.09596043300629E-4   4.538E-4       1100  -2.21895500564575E-5   
2       1110  3.50619777159691E-4  3.1748E-4       1110   2.84931027173996E-5   
3       1120  6.16795350761414E-4  5.6608E-4       1120  -1.23864640111923E-4   
4       1130  4.80301692390442E-4   4.456E-4       1130  -2.04537812271118E-4   
5       1140  4.28569921140671E-4  4.0088E-4       1140   -2.3310064260006E-4   

           S2 Wavelength                  S2c         S2 Wavelength  \
1   -1.976E-5       1100   5.1777114068985E-4  4.6108E-4       1100   
2     2.58E-5       1110  6.66738603587151E-4  6.0372E-4       1110   
3  -1.1368E-4       1120  3.66494637122154E-4  3.3636E-4       1120   
4  -1.8976E-4       1130  6.91522337903976E-4  6.4156E-4       1130   
5  -2.1804E-4       1140  4.32760686683655E-4   4.048E-4       1140   

                    S2c          S2 Wavelength                  S2c         S2  
1  -8.76127882289886E-4   -7.802E-4       1100  4.59871687202454E-4  4.0952E-4  
2  -6.62276892929077E-4  -5.9968E-4       1110  5.10048626317978E-4  4.6184E-4  
3  -8.10393778409958E-4  -7.4376E-4       1120   5.5015600004673E-4  5.0492E-4  
4   -7.0902704949379E-4   -6.578E-4       1130  3.71091262693405E-4  3.4428E-4  
5    -9.123467638731E-4   -8.534E-4       1140  3.56086782412529E-4  3.3308E-4
```

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is this data not 1-dimensional if it is not due to MultiIndexing?

It means there is duplicated columns names, so if use:

```
print (df['Wavelength'])
```

get all columns in 2d DataFrame.

If need groiping by `Wavelength` with aggregate `mean` change `axis=1` to `axis=0` and then use:

```
working = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list], ignore_index=False, axis = 0)
#if necessary
#working = working.drop(['Wavelength.1'], axis=1)
#working = working.drop(index=0)
working.groupby(by='Wavelength').mean()
```

Comment: Okay, but is that not the whole point of `groupy()` which is to combine all columns with the same column names? How should I fix it  ?

Comment: @LukeTeo - Answer was edited, can you check?

Comment: that is indeed correct!! However, I dont quite understand why it should be axis = 0. Is groupby technically locating columns ?

Comment: `I dont quite understand why it should be axis = 0` - Reason is very simple - then output is only one unique `Wavelength`, one unique `S2c`, `S2` columns, if join with `axis=0`

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks alot for the help! I will be marking your answer as correct!